# Prestashop: send a 2nd confirmation email to a 2nd email address

Tags: email, prestashop

I need to add an option in Prestashop(for instance by ticking a box) to send the confirmation order email to another email address, if it's a gift for instance.

I added an email field to my addresses table and forms, but I do not know how to get that value afterward and send the confirmation to the email input there, I tried adding a send::mail in PaymentModule.php, without success.

Do you have in workaround this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the validateOrder() function in PaymentModule.php classes as this function is responsible for creating the order and sending order confirmation email as well.